# Editing a div tag

Tags: jquery

If I have 4 divs:

```
<div class="divData">data 1</div>
<div class="divData">data 2</div>
<div class="divData">data 3</div>
<div class="divData">data 4</div>
```

I know I can use `.length` to find out how many divs are on the page:

```
alert( $(".divData").length ); // returns 4
```

Is it possible to change the text in the 3rd div without is having an id and keeping the class name as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is using [`eq` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$(".divData").eq(2).text('foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. do `$(".divData:eq(2)")` then call your chain functions in order to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.divData').eq(2).text('Your Text Here');
```

Comment: jQuerys `.eq()` call takes a zero-based index.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
$('.divData').eq(2).text('myText');
```